# _Generic macro with void* pointers doesn't take a double argument?

Tags: c, macros, void

I try to implement _Generic macro which can take any data type and handle it, this sample works fine, but with 2 Generic macros, how can I implement this using only one Generic with char* int and double?

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

  #define puts(x) _Generic((x),              \
    char*:    _puts((void*) x, "str"),       \
    int:      _puts((void*) x, "int")        \
  )

  #define putsd(x) _Generic((x),\
    double: _puts((void*)to_s(x), "float") \
  )


  char*
  to_s(double x)
  {
    char* str = (char *)malloc(1502);
    sprintf(str, "%lf", x);
    free(str);
    return str;
  }

  void _puts(void* d, const char* type)
  {
    if (strcmp(type, "int") == 0){
      printf("%d\n", d);
    } else if (strcmp(type, "float") == 0){
      double res;
      sscanf(d, "%lf", &res);
      printf("%lf\n", res);
    } else {
      printf("%s\n", d);
    }
  }


  int main(void) {
    puts("String");
    puts(1230);
    putsd(13.37);

    return 0;
  }
```

Also when I try follows I get an error "incompatible type for argument 1 of 'to_s' puts("String");   :

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

  #define puts(x)                              \
    _Generic((x),                               \
        char*:    _puts((void*) x, "str"),       \
        int:      _puts((void*) x, "int"),        \
         double : _puts((void *)to_s(x), "float") \
        )


  char *to_s(double x) {
    char *str = (char *)malloc(1502);
    sprintf(str, "%lf", x);
    free(str);
    return str;
  }

  void _puts(void *d, const char *type) {
    if (strcmp(type, "int") == 0) {
        printf("%d\n", d);
    } else if (type == "float") {
        double res;
        sscanf(d, "%lf", &res);
        printf("%lf\n", res);
    } else {
        printf("%s\n", d);
    }
  }

  int main(void) {
    puts("String");
    puts(1230);
    puts(13.37);

    return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not compare strings with `==`

Change

```
if (type == "int") {
```

with

```
if (strcmp(type, "int") == 0) {
```

Same for `float` ...

On the other hand, you can not pass the address of a literal like `1230` or `13.39`, use intermediate pointers:

```
int i = 1230;
int *pi = &i;

puts(pi);
```

and then in your generic macro:

```
#define puts(x)                    \
    _Generic((x),                   \
        char*:    _puts((x), "str"), \
        int *:    _puts((x), "int"),  \
        double *: _puts((x), "float")  \
)
```

GLib uses some ugly tricks to pass literals (casting to `long`) as pointers, but this is not portable: [Type Conversion Macros](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Type-Conversion-Macros.html)

Also, notice that `puts` is the name of a function in the standard library, overwriting this name is not a good idea.

Your code corrected using compound literals in order to pass a pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define Puts(x)                \
    _Generic((x),               \
    char *:   _Puts((x), "str"), \
    int *:    _Puts((x), "int"),  \
    double *: _Puts((x), "float")  \
)

static void _Puts(void *d, const char *type)
{
    if (strcmp(type, "int") == 0) {
        printf("%d\n", *(int *)d);
    } else
    if (strcmp(type, "float") == 0) {
        printf("%f\n", *(double *)d);
    } else {
        printf("%s\n", (char *)d);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    Puts("String");
    Puts((int []){1230});
    Puts((double []) {13.37});   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the corrections and help, but when I change to
        int: _puts(&x, "int")
I get an error : "lvalue required as unary '&' operand", what's wrong with this?

Comment: This approach leads to unexpected 0.000 value instead of initial double value, maybe I miss something? I appreciate your help, and I fixed all issues that you noted.

https://ideone.com/jOp2wA

Comment: @Partylover, Yes, because you can not use a `double` as first argument of `fscanf`, you have an edit with your code corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You miss the whole point of generic, you create a function that exactly do what generic do (aka. `_puts()`. You should just use the correct function directly in your generic, plus `to_s()` free `str`... and you use it after ! That invoke undefined behavior. And don't use reserved function name of stdlib `puts()`

A good example is [here](http://www.robertgamble.net/2012/01/c11-generic-selections.html)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define printf_dec_format(x) _Generic((x), \
    char: "%c", \
    signed char: "%hhd", \
    unsigned char: "%hhu", \
    signed short: "%hd", \
    unsigned short: "%hu", \
    signed int: "%d", \
    unsigned int: "%u", \
    long int: "%ld", \
    unsigned long int: "%lu", \
    long long int: "%lld", \
    unsigned long long int: "%llu", \
    float: "%f", \
    double: "%f", \
    long double: "%Lf", \
    char *: "%s", \
    void *: "%p")

#define print(x) printf(printf_dec_format(x), x)
#define printnl(x) printf(printf_dec_format(x), x), printf("\n");

int main(void) {
    printnl('a');    // prints "97" (on an ASCII system)
    printnl((char)'a');  // prints "a"
    printnl(123);    // prints "123"
    printnl(1.234);      // prints "1.234000"
    printnl("hello");
}
```